# changing a program in c, so it takes an optional command line argument *infile*

Tags: c, file-io

Now I do have a hw question for everyone...I've been staring at this for a couple of days kind of tinkering and playing around but even with that I end up with a load of errors...

What I'm trying to do is take the program below and change it so that it takes an optional command line argument ***infile***. If ***infile*** is given, then copy ***infile*** to standard output, otherwise copy standard input to standard output as before.

The trick about this is that the solution must use the original copy loop (lines 9-11) for both cases.  One can only insert code, and not change any of the existing code.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

```
/* $begin cpfile */
include "csapp.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    rio_t rio;
    char buf[MAXLINE];

    Rio_readinitb(&rio, STDIN_FILENO);                  //line 9
    while((n = Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE)) != 0) //line 10
        Rio_writen(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);              //line 11
        /* $end cpfile */
        exit(0);
        /* $begin cpfile */
    }
/* $end cpfile */
```

Comment: @jitter: .. in this case, its obviously homework. The question itself screams that with a resounding echo. He probably did not know that the tag existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert `dup2` before the lines 9 - 11 and it seems that you will not need change code on the lines 9 - 11. This is an example.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int file_handle;
    int dup2_res;
    if (argc == 2) {
        file_handle = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        dup2_res = dup2 (file_handle, STDIN_FILENO);
    }

    char buffer[100];
    ssize_t read_bytes = 1;
    while (read_bytes)
    {
        read_bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
        buffer[read_bytes] = 0;
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    close(file_handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to make it clear that dup2() isn't ANSI C, and OP didn't specify the platform so it is not necessarily kosher.

Comment: True, but dup2() is POSIX. But sure, it is dependent on the platform.

Answer (score 5):

C programs get command line arguments through the two arguments to `main()`, traditionally called `argc` and `argv` (for argument count and argument vector, respectively).

Arguments are not "named" anything, they're just strings.

A solution for you could look like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fileno;
    /* ... your definitions should remain here, too */

    if(argc > 1)
    {
       /* Assume first argument is filename, and open it. */
       fileno = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
       if(fileno < 0)
       {
         printf("Unable to open file, aborting\n");
         return 1;
       }
    }
    else
      fileno = STDIN_FILENO;

  /* ... your code goes here ... */
}
```

Then you'd of course need to change the call to `Rio_readinitb()` to use the `fileno` variable for the file descriptor.

If you literally can't change that line, for whatever reason ... I guess you can use the preprocessor to make the symbol evaluate to the new variable name:

```
#undef  STDIN_FILENO
#define STDIN_FILENO fileno
```

This is of course not exactly pretty, but should work.

Make sure you put those preprocessor macros *after* the `fileno = STDIN_FILENO;` line.

Comment: That would require changing the lines that cannot be changed.

Comment: But if you can't change the `STDIN_FILENO` in the call to `Rio_readinitb(&rio, STDIN_FILENO);` the you will always read from stdin. Likewise the call `exit(0);` in the loop is spurious.
This assignment does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @unwind, I clarified to make sure you didn't #define until the right spot. +1 for being sneaky :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Heh ... Thanks. I think that you perceived a bit more sneakyness than intended, but it should work that way so I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

If `STDIN_FILENO` cannot be reassigned, it sounds like a task for `freopen()`:

```
freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);
```